# Can MongoDB automatically generate special indexes for geolocation data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, geolocation, mongoid

I currently have a Mongoid model in a Ruby on Rails application as such:

```
class Listen
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :song_title, type: String
    field :song_artist, type: String
    field :loc, :type => Array
    field :listened_at, type: Time, default: -> { Time.now }

    index(
        [[:loc, Mongo::GEO2D]], background: true
    )
end
```

When I try to query the collection for example

```
listens = Listen.where(:loc => {"$within" => {"$centerSphere" => [location, (radius.fdiv(6371))]}})
```

I am returned the error (locations have been blanked out, the X's are not returned)

```
Mongo::OperationFailure (can't find special index: 2d for: { loc: { $within: { $centerSphere: [ [ XX.XXXXXXX, X.XXXXXXX ], 0.0001569612305760477 ] } } }):
```

I know I can create the indexed through a rake task such as `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes` but I don't want to have to do this every time a model is created. Is there any way for the model to create this automatically on insert to the collection?

Comment: You should not need to create an index after the model instance is saved to the collection. Is that what you're seeing you need to do? It should be done once, when you define the model.

Comment: After creating the model the BSON ID is created but when I attempt to run a query on the collection, such as the one listed above, it throws the `can't find special index` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope there is no way.

You must create indexes (not just Geo) once, to use it.

Comment: Is there anyway the model can do this on creation? It creates the BSON ID but doesn't allow querying of location. Thanks for the information.

Comment: I believe the issue I was encountering was because every now and again I would drop the collection and forget I would have to run `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes` again. After I run this once, I don't receive this error any more.